# what is the byte order of received packets

Tags: network-programming

I want to write a receiver program using raw socket
it will use recvfrom() to receive packets
so I want to check the IP header and tcp header of a packet

when a program sends a packet, it will pay attention to the network byte order and host byte order problem
but for my recever program, when I use `recvfrom(sockfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);`

what is the byte order of the data in the packets? it is network byte order or host byte order?
and how to deal with it?

for this example
http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-in-c-using-linux-sockets-bsd/

the author doesn't take into account the byte order problem when dealing with the received packets, why?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the byte order of the data in the packets?

The convention is that network order is big endian order. However, the data you receive is the data you sent: nobody magically modifies "integers" to change their endianness.

> and how to deal with it?

- Use `ntohl` and `ntohs` when interpreting integer data
- Be aware that bitfield endianness isn't standard

> the author doesn't take into account the byte order problem when
>   dealing with the received packets,

The link you posted shows `ntohs` and `ntohl` calls. The author **does handle endianness** at least to some extent.

Comment: but in the link the author doesn't take into acccount the order problem, why?

Comment: you meant there are some problems in the author's program because he doesn't carefully think on endianness problems?

Comment: @user138126 I didn't read the entire code. I merely mentioned the author handles endianness, at least to some extent. The code could well be completely correct as it stands.

Comment: I don't understand this: nobody magically modifies "integers" to change their endianness.

Comment: And if I have no idea on the sender program and don't know the byte order of the sent data, can I still use ntohs and ntohl. In other words, even if the byte order is host byte order, I can still use these two functions?

Comment: @user138126 If you write an integer, without using something like `ntohs()` to put it into a standard order, it will be sent in whatever byte order the sending machine uses natively.

Comment: @user138126 The protocol at each layer specifies how the data is interpreted. If you're designing a protocol that sends binary data, you must specify its encoding, which includes byte order. If you don't know the byte order that data was sent, you don't know how to read it.

Comment: so why we need to change host byte order to network byte order? in order that the router can recogonize the packets?

Comment: Yes, that's part of the definition of the TCP and IP protocols.

Comment: Using the wrong byte order would be like putting the postal code backwards on an envelope -- the post office won't know how to deliver the mail.